# Enorm, riesig und gewaltig - der Unterschied

Tags: difference, synonym

Der Duden sagt:

> **riesig:** 
>    **1.a** außerordentlich, übermäßig groß, umfangreich; gewaltig
>     **1.b** das normale Maß weit übersteigend; einen übermäßig hohen Grad aufweisend; gewaltig
>
> **enorm** 
>       **1.a** außerordentlich; ungewöhnlich [groß]
>       **1.b** äußerst, sehr
>
> **gewaltig**
>  **2.a** eine außerordentliche Größe oder Stärke aufweisend; den Eindruck übergroßer Kraft oder Wucht erweckend 
> **2.b** das normale Maß weit übersteigend

Gibt's einen Unterschied zwischen den Wörtern?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Betrachten wir die Etymologie der Wörter:

### riesig

Dieses Wort hat zu Beginn des 19. Jahrhunderts das Wort *riesicht* abgelöst und völlig verdrängt. Der Ursprung ist aber ganz klar erkennbar das Nomen *Riese*, von dem auch *riesenhaft* (entstanden im 17. Jhd) abgeleitet ist.

Ein Riese ist ein mythisches Wesen, häufig auch eine Märchenfigur, deren auffallendstes Merkmal der große Wuchs ist. Etymologen tappen bei der Suche nach der Herkunft des Wortes *Riese* weitgehend im Dunkeln, halten aber das griechische *rhion* (Vorgebirge, Bergspitze) für eine mögliche Wurzel, was mit der Beobachtung übereinstimmt, dass Riesen häufig in gebirgigen Gegenden verortet werden. Ein Riese könnte also ursprünglich möglicherweise einfach jemand gewesen sein, der in den Bergen wohnt. Erst später wurde daraus jemand, der groß wie ein Berg ist.

Tatsache ist aber, dass die eigentliche Bedeutung von *riesig* »besonders groß« ist, wobei damit vor allen die räumliche Ausdehnung, und dabei wieder primär die Höhe, im Zentrum der Betrachtung stehen. Davon abgeleitet ist die Bedeutung von »übermäßig gesteigert«, die eigentlich auf alles anwendbar ist, was sich steigern lässt

> Das Fest war ein riesiger Spaß, und ich konnte dort meinen riesigen Durst stillen.
>   Hans hat eine riesige Nase.

### enorm

Dieses Wort drang im 18. Jahrhundert aus der französischen Sprache in den deutschen Wortschatz ein (*énorme*) und hat seinen Ursprung im lateinischen *e-normis*, das wiederum als Zusammenziehung von *ex normis* verstanden werden kann. Es bedeutet »außerhalb der Norm«, also eigentlich »nicht gewöhnlich« bzw. »ungewöhnlich«.

Tatsächlich ist damit aber eine spezielle Ungewöhnlichkeit gemeint, nämlich eine außergewöhnlich gesteigerte Größe.

Das deutsche Wort *enorm* bedeutet also - zumindest aufgrund seiner Herkunft - dasselbe wie *riesig*.

Einen kleinen, kaum wahrnehmbaren Unterschied zwischen *enorm* und *riesig* gibt es aber: Bei *enorm* schwingt manchmal (eher selten) ein wenig die Betonung der als abstoßend empfundenen Abnormität mit, während das bei *riesig* nicht der Fall ist.

> Das Fest war ein enormer Spaß, und ich konnte dort meinen enormen Durst stillen.
>   Hans hat eine enorme Nase.

### gewaltig

Dieses Adjektiv stammt, ebenso wie das Nomen *Gewalt* vom Verb *walten* ab, das in der Fügung »schalten und walten« und in abgewandelter Form im Verb »verwalten« auch in der modernen Sprache weiterlebt. Auch als Nomen (*Walter*, z.B. in *Sachwalter* oder auch *Verwalter*) besteht diesen Wort weiter.

Das Verb *walten* hat ein weites Bedeutungsfeld, das ungefähr mit *beherrschen*, *verursachen*, *besitzen*, *regieren* und *pflegen* umschrieben werden kann.

Derjenige, der waltet, ist der *Walter* (vergl.: *Sachwalter*, *Verwalter*). Er hat *Ge-walt* (also eine Befugnis) über das, das er beherrscht. Zusätzlich muss der Walter stark sein (körperlich kräftig und auch im übertragenen Sinn mächtig) um auch tatsächlich walten zu können, und diese Eigenschaft kommt besonders im Wort *Gewalt* zum Ausdruck.

*Gewalt* wird heute häufig mit aggressivem Körpereinsatz gleichgesetzt, ist aber tatsächlich die Fähigkeit Macht auszuüben. Dennoch ist jemand, der Gewalt ausüben kann (egal ob im agressiv-körperlichen Sinn, oder z.B. im Form einer Behörde, die Vorschriften machen kann), gewaltig, also mächtig.

Anhand der Wort-Herkunft lässt sich also nur eine geringe Übereinstimmung zwischen *gewaltig* und *riesig/enorm* feststellen. Nichts desto trotz scheinen sich die Bedeutungen dieser Wörter so weit aneinander angeglichen zu haben, dass heute nur mehr ein geringer Unterschied feststellbar ist.

Meiner Wahrnehmung nach schwingt in »gewaltig« aber dennoch ein aggressiver Unterton mit, der bei den beiden anderen Wörtern nicht so hervortritt.

> Das Fest war ein gewaltiger Spaß, und ich konnte dort meinen gewaltigen Durst stillen.
>   Hans hat eine gewaltige Nase.

Comment: Sehr gut dargestellt. Darüberhinaus scheint "enorm" das einzige Wort (aus den dreien) zu sein, das man auch zur Steigerung anderer Eigenschaften einsetzen kann. "enorm reich", "enorm schwierig" usw. geht, dasselbe mit "riesig" oder "gewaltig" nicht so.

Comment: Insofern wäre die Entsprechung von "enorm" das schöne Wort "arg", so wie es im Süden Deutschlands verwendet wird: "I han di ganz arg liab." Während es in anderen Gegenden fast ausschließlich in abwertenden Zusammenhängen gebraucht wird. Arg schade!

Comment: @Ingo Für Freunde der Dänischen Oper würde noch "mächtig" in die Liste gehören, Da gibt es dann "mächtig gewaltig".

Answer (score 3):

Nicht direkt, obwohl man nicht immer jedes Wort in jedem Kontext benutzen kann; manchmal passt eines einfach besser, oder es handelt sich um feststehende Redewendungen. Die Parallele zu *gigantic*, *enormous* oder *huge* drängt sich auf.

Answer (score -2):

riesig   =            überdimensional groß

gewaltig =            massiv